# Taking odd value of n in Simpson Rule

Tags: integration

I have one doubt in Simpson rule. In this rule,  we calculate $\Delta x = \frac{(b-a)}{n}$ where $n$ is taken to be even. Will Simpson rule work if we take $n$ to be odd?

Answer (score 2):

No, because you first divide the interval into $\frac n2$ intervals, then use the rule on each one, dividing it in half again.  You need the first $\frac n2$ to be an integer. [Simpson's $\frac 38$ rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Simpson.27s_3.2F8_rule) is also exact on cubic polynomials.  The basic rule uses four points, so three intervals.  If you chain these together you need $n$ divisible by $3$.

Comment: I tried writing a prog based on Simpsons rule where I took odd value of n as well as even value. Still I got almost similar output with little difference

Comment: I don't know what it means to use Simpson with an odd number of intervals.  With an even number the result is $\frac 16(y_0+4y_1+2y+2+4y_3+2y_4+\ldots 4y_{n-1}+y_n)$.  The alternation does not work out if you have an odd number of intervals.  Just leaving out the $4y_{n-1}$ will make the result no longer exact for polynomials of degree less than $4$, but it will still be close.

Comment: I searched google for it. Google shows that the Simpson rule can be modified to Simpson one-third rule where the value of n can be taken odd.